# Given I know the coordinates of a rectangle, how can I find the coordinates of an enlarged rectangle?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a rectangle, and know the dimensions, coordinates of the 4 corner points and therefore the centre point.

If I scaled it up e.g. scalefactor * height, from its centre, how can I find the new corner point coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any number of points
$(P_i)_{i=1}^n
=((x_i, y_i))_{i=1}^n
$
and a center
$C
=(x_c, y_c)
$,
here's how I would
expand by a factor $f$
around $C$:

The line through
$C$ and $P_i$
is,
in vector form,
$L_i
=C+t(P_i-C)
$.
This is $C$ for $t=0$
and
$P_i$ for $t=1$.

To expand
this by a factor of $f$
around $C$,
just take
$t=f$,
so the point is
$C+f(P_i-C)
$.
To get the coordinates,
just compute coordinate-wise.

This works for any number of points
and any number of dimensions.

Note that
the basic idea
is to transform the points
so that the center is the origin,
do what you want to do,
and than transform back
to the original coordinate system.

Comment: Any chance of this being in laymans terms?

Comment: Sure. However far you have to go from the center to each point, multiply that length by the scale factor (2 for twice as long) and go that far.

Comment: Guessing this only works for a uniform scale? Whats the equation for finding the length between two points?

Comment: How exactly can I get the coords of the new corner (assume I have a new line form the centre through the top left corner)

Answer (score 0):

You need only multiplying the coordinates in the appropriate dimension by your scale factor. You need to mind what your origin is, however, as although the distance between the point will change,  your origin will remain in the same place....

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Hmm not really, my Math etc is terrible! Does this work for a rectangle that has been rotated? Could you provide some more info or an equation for translating the points?

Comment: Rotations are based on trigonometry and even get into matrix math, but rotating a point (x,y) around a center (a,b) by angle $\Theta$ to boils down to the point at $((x-a)\cos{\Theta}+(y-b)\sin{\Theta} + a, -(x-a)\sin{\Theta}+(y-b)\cos{\Theta} + b)$.

Comment: If your scale factor applies to the whole plane then yes. If you want to enlarge and then rotate you need to do as Keith says...

Comment: I'm still unsure how to multiple the coords by the scale factor. I tried what I think it is, but it seems to be totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By finding the center point of the rectangle, you can define four (eight actually, but keep reading) right triangles, with the center, the corner, and the center of the two "sides" (as distinct from the "top" and "bottom"). The two right-angle sides of these triangles are equivalent to the translations, in the X and Y dimensions, between the center point and each corner. They're also half the X and Y dimensions of the entire rectangle.

Knowing these measurements, to scale the rectangle while keeping the same center point, you simply have to scale the sides of these triangles by your scale factor to determine the offsets of the new corners from the same center point.

As the simplest example, consider a rectangle that is 2 units by 4 units centered at the origin (0,0). Its corners are (2,1), (2, -1), (-2, -1) and (-2, 1). To construct a rectangle with twice the dimensions of the original rectangle (which will quadruple its area), you simply subtract the center coordinate from these numbers (which is a "no-op" because the center is at 0,0), double that, then add the center coordinate again. This will produce a rectangle with corners at (4,2), (4,-2), (-4,-2) and (-4,2).

Comment: Sorry I really can't visualise this. Can you draw up a diagram?